# python - imported functions from another file works slow

Tags: python, function, python-import

I am importing functions from another py script I wrote, saved in the same directory.
While the import works ,the imported functions take several minutes to run instead of seconds. Any ideas how to solve it?

```
from CX_Plug import GET_URL
```

GET_URL:

```
def GET_URL():
    P=pd.read_csv('C:/PY/Paths.csv',index_col=0)
    URL=P.loc[Brand]['url']
    URL=str(URL)
    return URL
```

Comment: You will have to post details. Most important: your code!

Comment: from CX_Plug import GET_URL

Comment: this is the line i am using  cx_plug is the file URL is the function. its a super simple function that works super fast on the source code

Comment: Add **all** code to the **question** as code-formatted text!

Comment: What does `GET_URL` do? How are you calling it?

Comment: Yea 100% the problem is not how you are importing it. We need to see the code in CX_Plug. Specifically in GET_URL

Comment: absolutely!  just added the function above

Comment: So you're saying the program is taking a long time when it starts up because of the import? Or are you calling the function somewhere?

Comment: i am calling the function and its running for something like 5min compared to the actual file where the function rests , where it takes maybe 10 seconds.

Comment: Does importing GET_URL by doing import CX_Plug and running CX_Plug.GET_URL() have any effect?

Comment: no same issue even with CX_Plug.GET_URL()

Comment: How are you calling GET_URL? Do you have any unintentional loops?

Comment: no its very straight forward it pulls a text from a csv file , no loops or anything that could complicate the import.

Comment: Your code is not even valid! It throws a SyntaxError.

Comment: def GET_URL: needs to be def GET_URL():

Comment: sorry i did not copy it correctly it is GET_URL() in the script